# Multi-select Filter Checkbox with dynamic array values

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-plugins, multipleselection, jquery-forms-plugin

- https://github.com/andreww1011/filter-multi-select (Github)
- https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/multi-select-filter-checkbox.html

I have been trying to replicate the above Multi-select Filter Checkbox with Dynamic Array values for my project.

`arr=[&callback\\ | &s\\ | action | app]` this is a dynamic array that the user selected and saved this array value can change according to the users selection

This function `createFiledSelectEnrich(fileds)` will create a select field in the page that display dynamic `key` values in the options tag

```
function createFiledSelectEnrich(fileds) {
        var select = '<select multiple name="fieldSelected" class="form-control form-control-cust" id="fieldSelect">';
        for ( var key in fileds) {
            var option = $("<option>", {
                "value" : key
            }).text(key).data("customData", fileds[key]);
            console.log('option:' + option + ',  option.html:'
                    + option[0].outerHTML);
            select += option[0].outerHTML;
        }
        select += '</select>';
        //clear existing fields & add new fields
        $("#fieldSelectDiv").empty().append(select);
    }
```

This code gets the `arr` value from the response and convert in to array that can further processed to be able to show the value that is selected by the user earlier in the Multi-select Filter Checkbox

```
var enrichmentField = "${enrichmentField}";
const options = $('#fieldSelect').filterMultiSelect({
            // displayed when no options are selected
            placeholderText : "Select at-least one",
            // placeholder for search field
            filterText : "Search",
            // Select All text
            selectAllText : "Select All",
        });
        //regex remove delimiter and whitespaces 
        var arr = enrichmentField.split(/\s*\|\s*/);
        if (options) {
            arr.forEach(function(value) {
                console.log("value :", value);
                options.selectOption(value);
            });
        } else {
            console.error("Multi-select component not initialized properly");
        }
```

ERROR that i am facing with no output
[image]

```
<label for="multiselectop" class="form-label">Multiselect</label> 
<select multiple name="multiselect" id="multiselectop">
        <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
        <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
        <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

```
<script>
    $(document)
            .ready(
                    function() {

                        var arr = [ "cheese", "tomatoes", "mozarella",
                                "mushrooms", "pepperoni", "onions" ];

                        //Multi-Select: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/multi-select-filter-checkbox.html
                        //const options = $('#multiselectop').filterMultiSelect();
                        const options = $('#multiselectop').filterMultiSelect({

                            // displayed when no options are selected
                            placeholderText : "Select at-least one",

                            // placeholder for search field
                            filterText : "Filter",

                            // Select All text
                            selectAllText : "Select All",

                        });
                        console.log(arr);

                        if (options) {
                            // Iterate over the array and select each option
                            arr.forEach(function(value) {
                                // Assuming selectOption is the method to select an option
                                options.selectOption(value);
                            });
                        } else {
                            console
                                    .error("Multi-select component not initialized properly");
                        }
</script>
```

Expecting the output for the Above Problem to be in this format
[image]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, the error which you are getting in console is because your `select` element yet not added and you are trying to initialising it `$('#fieldSelect').filterMultiSelect..` so make sure your select is present in DOM when you call your initialising code. Working fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/73z6Lea9/)